# Form_for with render list of check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkboxlist

I have functionality search above tags. I want to render all tags with check_box in form_for that I will filter those tags and render all items again with new parameters.

```
= form_for @tags do |f|
  - @tags.each do |tag|
    f.check_box(#{tag}, "yes")
    f.label_tag "#{tag}"
  f.submit 'Filter'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are asking because your question is not much clear, but trying to understand your question. If I understood your question then you need to add a filter with tags on the search page, right? If yes then try the following steps.

Create a form for search tag like

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
   <% for tag in Model.order("name") %> #=> Model means which stored your tags like "Tag"
       <%= check_box_tag("#{tag.name}[]", "#{tag.name}") %> tag.name
       OR
       <%= check_box_tag("tags[]", "#{tag.name}") %> tag.name
   <% end %>
   <%= submit_tag "Filter" %>
<% end %>
```

**Or** If you need filter separately clicking link and keep current search then

```
   <% for tag in Model.order("name") %> #=> Model means which stored your tags like "Tag"
       <%= link_to tag.name, request.query_parameters.merge({tag: tag.name}) %>
   <% end %>
```

See the below image for keep current search and filter by clicking on the link

[image]

These all are view functionality, you need to update your SQL query.

I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
= form_tag({controller: 'searches', action: 'filter'}, method: 'get') do
  ul
    - @tags.each do |tag|
      li
        input type='checkbox' name="tags[]" checked="checked" id="#{tag}" value="#{tag}"
        label_tag for="#{tag}" #{tag}
  button Filter
```